# Ajax request 500 interval error

Tags: python, ajax, flask, request

I am using Python Flask framework to build my website. I try to use ajax call to get server response and result in 500 internal error.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request
@app.route(''+'/api/suggest/')
def api():
   pass
```

**index.js**

```
new Ajax.Request('api/suggest/',{
    method: 'get',
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

http://localhost:5000/api/suggest/ returns 500 Internal server error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: Did you run your flask app to make sure that it works? From what I can see, if that is your code, it's not looking too good.

Comment: @idjaw yea localhost:5000 works fine for me

Comment: `@app.route(""+/api/suggest")` but that is wrong. Are you showing the exact code on your end?

Comment: @idjaw My mistake in the post. It should be @app.route(''+'/api/suggest'), still get same error.

Comment: `''+'/api/suggest/'` is the same as `'/api/suggest/'`.

Comment: OK....so that means you actually have a method with `pass` in it. You *need* to return something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your `api()` function needs to return something, rather than pass. If you pass the function, it has a return value of `None` and messes up with your `alert(response)`. Instead, you should do:

```
def api():
    return {}
```

or

```
def api():
    return "Testing"
```